# Cherrypy vs. Apache/mod_wsgi

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, cherrypy

What are pros/cons?

-Stability

-Developer friendliness

-System resources

-Scalability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience the best performance is by running a WSGI app with a WSGI server like FAPWS or gevent (some benchmarks here: http://nichol.as/benchmark-of-python-web-servers).  Then you can configure nginx with `proxy_pass`.